# What's wrong in my WPF EventTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I am new in WPF. I have a problem using EventTrigger.
I have two Buttons(bt1 and bt1) and a StackPanel(stackpanel) in a Grid.

bt1 and stackpanel are Visible at first. And bt2 is Collapsed.

I have two targets(finished it in XAML only):

1. When Click bt1, the stackpanel and bt1 will be Collapsed, bt2 will be Visible.
2. When Click bt2, the stackpanel and bt1 will be Visible. bt2 will be Collapsed.

I just finished target one. But the code didnot work. What's wrong with it?

```
    <Grid Name="Grid">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackpanel" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=bt1, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="bt1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Height="20">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="stackpanel"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bt2"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                   >
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"></DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Button Name="bt2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `stackpanel` and `btn2` are defined **outside** of the visual-tree of `btn1.Style`. Moreover there is no need to style `btn1` to achieve this sort of behavior.

Therefore instead of using `Style.Triggers` :

```
<Button Name="bt1" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                ....
```

Define your `EventTriggers` directly in your `Button.Trrigers`.

```
<Button Name="bt1" >
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
        ....
```